# how to print some portion of a line from a file in windows cmd

Tags: windows

hi I have a file having data like

```
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2800
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2801
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2802
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2803
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2804
```

here I want to print the line removing Link: word like

```
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2800
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2801
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2802
```

please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use PowerShell instead of Command Line.

Assign that link to a string and extract a substring from it.

Here's a guide I found from a quick Google search: https://4sysops.com/archives/strings-in-powershell-replace-compare-concatenate-split-substring/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Copy below code into text file and save the file, filename.cmd and run file from command prompt.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
 set line=%%A
 echo !line:~6! >> output.txt
)
```

input.txt

```
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2800
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2801
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2802
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2803
Link: tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2804
```

Result in output.txt

```
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2800 
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2801 
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2802 
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2803 
tds://ACC.GA.mfqc.ams1907.com:8443/qcbin//TestLabModule-000000003649890581?EntityType=IRun&EntityID=2804
```